# Changing <strong> tag to <b> CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

So, I'm using CKEditor for wordpress. But when I select **B** to change to bold, it uses `<strong>` tag. I want to change it to `<b>`

How and Where I do that?

Version: 4.5.3.3

Comment: Why should one prefer `<b>` over `<strong>`?

Comment: Oh and this is off topic. It has imho nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Clijsters for some reason, my wordpress layout doesn't accept `<strong>` tag. It doesn't gets bold

Answer (score 0):

The style definition that applies the bold style to the text, defined in:

> plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js

```
config.coreStyles_bold = { element : 'b', overrides : 'strong' };
config.coreStyles_bold = {
  element : 'span',
  attributes : { 'class' : 'Bold' }
 };
```

Check the documentation for more info (it's quite comprehensive so brace yourself :)):

https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.coreStyles_bold

Comment: There is no **plugins/basicstyles** folder @Ted

Comment: There is definitely a `plugin.js` in the CKEditor folder structure.

Comment: Apparently we have different versions of the editor, so check the `plugins` folder for any `config` file or do a find-in-files searching for `config.`

Comment: Can u send me your version. So I can edit, because i'm not finding it

Comment: you wouldn't want mine, it's 10 years old and has issues with new browsers :(. I'm using CKEditor in a legacy web app

Comment: I opened the config.js and... `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
 // config.language = 'fr';
 // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.coreStyles_bold = { element : 'b', overrides : 'strong' };
config.coreStyles_bold = {
  element : 'span',
  attributes : { 'class' : 'Bold' }
 };
};
`

Comment: Try downloading the latest version